# Javascript if/else on submit

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

im totally new to javascript and im currently working on my first functions.
I have these 2 text input area where one can put his name and his level.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
Nom: <input type="text" name="fullname"><br><br>
Niveau (1 &aacute; 6): <input type="text" name="niveau">
<input type="submit" value="Afficher partie 2">
</form>
```

After submitting, the user is supposed to be shown a message with his name and his level (if level is between 1-6, else its an error message).

This is how i wrote my script:

```
<script>
var x = oninput;
var y = oninput;
if (y>=1){
  document.write("Bonjour + 'x'");
  document.write("Niveau='y'");
}if (y<=6){
  document.write("Bonjour + 'x'");
  document.write("Niveau='y'");
}
else {
  document.write("<p style="color:red;">Erreur le niveau doit etre en  
  1 et 6</p>
}
</script>
```

I really wanted to know if I wrote that the right way, I also cant figure how to show the user his name with the variable X.

I also have a problem understanding how to link my script to the input box.

Comment: Is your script in `action_page.php`?  If not, it's not going to get called by the submit.  Also, since it's presumably php your question should have `php` as a tag ... or it's not php in which case it probably needs to be renamed (possible, since your script is obviously JavaScript) ... or you're not actually intending on sending anything to `action_page.php` at all, in which case ... you probably shouldn't be using a submit

Comment: I have to do it by javascript. I cant figure out a way to make the script return to the user the info is entering in the boxes.

Comment: Because you're using a `submit` button, the browser will immediately navigate away from the current page (even if it goes to the same page) after the submit action has been evaluated.  This means that your values are only going to be available as part of server side processing, since they have been converted into the HTTP GET query that your browser will have created

Comment: What should I change the submit for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I hope it'll works

On your form,

```
<form name="form1" action="/action_page.php">
  Nom: <input type="text" name="fullname"><br><br>
  Niveau (1 &aacute; 6): <input type="text" name="niveau">
  <input type="submit" value="Afficher partie 2" onclick="myFunction()">
</form>
```

On your script

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.form1.fullname.value;
    var y = document.form1.niveau.value;

    if (y >= 1 && y <= 6) {
        document.write("Bonjour " +x);
        document.write("Niveau=" +y);
    } else {
        document.write("<p style='color:red;'>Erreur le niveau doit etre en 
        1 et 6</p>");
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue with string concatenation

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript have plenty of error. I cleaned it all up for you. Just read through the comments to understand what the JS is doing. Have fun :)

```js
  function showmylevel(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent Form Actually Submitting
    var x = document.getElementsByName('fullname')[0].value; // Get Value
    var y = document.getElementsByName('niveau')[0].value; // Get Value
    console.log(y);
    if ( y>0 && y<7 ){
      document.write("Bonjour "+x); // Display Name
      document.write("<br>"); // Break Line
      document.write("Niveau = "+y); // Display Level
    } else {
      // Display Error
      document.write('<p style="color:red;">Erreur le niveau doit etre en 1 et 6</p>');
    }
    return false; // Stop Form From Going Anywhere
  }
```

```html
<form action="action_page.php" onsubmit="showmylevel(event);">
Nom: <input type="text" name="fullname"><br><br>
Niveau (1 &aacute; 6): <input type="text" name="niveau"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Afficher partie 2">
</form>
```

Comment: In case you're wondering why I pass event variable in showmylevel function? It is for cross-platform purpose. Firefox doesn't have global event so you should pass it to the function to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, im looking at both responses and the thing im struggling the most is understanding where the script goes and the action_page.php thing. as im trying all this im really confused on where does the function go and the form go. Everytime I try it tells me error file not found when i hit the button.

Comment: right now i fixed it i dont have the error file not found, but it links me back to the code. unlike in the snippet

Comment: ok it works!!! ignore the other comments, now my only problem is I would like the text to not appear in a new page but right under the submit button, what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of your code that does not do a submit, but rather attaches an event handler to a button and appends to the DOM instead of rewriting it.  Attaches event handlers using addEventListener as putting onclick handlers in HTML is considered bad form.

```js
function do_stuff() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("fullname")[0].value;
  var y = document.getElementsByName("niveau")[0].value;
  if (parseInt(y)>=1 && parseInt(y)<=6){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Bonjour "+x));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Niveau='"+y+"'"));
  }
  else {
    var p = document.createElement('P');
    p.style.color = "red";
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Erreur le niveau doit etre en 1 et 6"));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  for(let input of document.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
    if (input.type == "button") { input.addEventListener( "click", do_stuff ); }
  }
}, false );
```

```html
<form>
Nom: <input type="text" name="fullname"><br><br>
Niveau (1 &aacute; 6): <input type="text" name="niveau">
<input type="button" value="Afficher partie 2">
</form>
```